# Restore: Any Solution?

Tags: cyanogenmod, restore, system-apps

Presently, running on cyanogenmod 13, I need to switch the device to cyanogenmod 14. But, the problem is that, I need to restore my contacts, call log and messages to newer version.  I have tried using Titanium backup, but it Force closes system apps on new version.  I also know that, this is due to compatibility issue of different android versions. Any solution to try out?

Comment: yes. it worked well (from MIUI to CM13).  I will try it from cm13 to cm14, when a bug-less cm14 available. It will definitely works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Super Backup: SMS and contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts) is a good choice , though I haven't tried it on CM.

You can backup `SMS/ Call logs/ contacts` to your `Google drive` account or you can mail them to yourself (even schedule, if required). It has a bunch of other features. I have used it for a while without any issues