# How can I delete synchronized Google data? (contacts, app data etc)

Tags: sync, google, privacy, delete

Apparently Google synchronized various data without my explicit permission. I don't want Google (and any parties that will ever have access to their data) to fetch any of my personal data without me allowing it!

Now I would like to at least transmit to them to delete it. How can I do that? I didn't find anything in the Google Dashboard. And there's no option to delete under Settings->Accounts->Google where I expected to find such a setting.

Answer (score 2):

1. Back up your contacts on phone using any app from play store ( see [Restore: Any Solution?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/160460/131553))
   (also note the contacts app has an export and import function built-in, so you won't necessarily need any 3rd party app for that)
2. Do the same for other synchronized data you want to keep (e.g. calendar; no built-in solution here, but you might pick an app [from Izzy's list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup))
3. Disable Google Sync on your phone Setting → Accounts → Google including Gmail ( on Marshmallow, may vary on other versions)
4. Go to https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/?cplus=1#contacts and select all for deletion
5. Repeat that for other affected data (calendars etc.)

Remove Gmail account from your phone and use web version of Gmail from Chrome or any other browser to prevent Gmail contacts getting synced again ( In earlier Android versions you could selectively stop contacts from syncing but I have noticed that contacts sync even if you specifically don't want them to )

If you disable backup (under settings) - none of the apps you installed will be backed up adding to cutting off from Google.

To prevent the mishap in future times, see e.g. [How to prevent Google from “synchronizing” my personal data after a factory-reset, adding a new Google account or software updates?](/q/182336/16575)

Comment: One important point: Right after a factory-reset (or whenever a new Google account is enabled on a device), sync will be on again as that's the default (and the reason Google once got my data at all, years ago). So I strongly recommend establishing a separate storage for that, e.g. by using DAVDroid, and making that the default for your calendars, contact apps etc. That way you can prevent accidental syncs for the future.

Comment: But it also displays under Accounts -> Google and is hence within the scope of this question. I just edited the title for better clarity. @Izzy Thank you too. As nobody else seems to have done this I asked about this in separate question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182336/how-to-prevent-google-from-synchronizing-my-personal-data-after-a-factory-rese). You can post some more details there (or edit my answer).

Comment: @beeshyams honestly, I don't remember exactly (it's half a year ago). But glad to see you back, I gave it an edit to the best I remembered. Hope it looks fine for you?

Comment: @izzy: Thanks and absolutely love the last point *To prevent the mishap in future times...*

Comment: @beeshyams Yupp. That was actually a follow-up question made by the OP. Just placed it there for the benefit of other readers :)