# Do a Fairphone 2 backup without Google-Services

Tags: backup, restore

I ran into some problems with my Fairphone 2 and it has to be fully replaced. So I'd like to backup my information including contacts, sms, wi-fi passwords and if possible too Whatsapp-conversations.

Now it's not like Fairphone doesn't provide a [tutorial for backing up your phone](https://www.fairphone.com/en/2016/05/12/how-to-back-up-your-fairphone-2-2/). The issue is it completely relies on Google Services and means I'm going to store all kinds of private information voluntary on random Google-Servers.

As I'm also using that phone for work and university I was advised *NOT* to share everything with Google.

I have been trying Titanium-Backup, but for that it's necessary to root the phone. (Well, and before I do that I'd surely like to backup everything so...)

So Helium seems to be a good option. The app is downloaded and on my Linux I got the their scrips, connected my phone, opened the app and typed:

```
qohelet@ubuntu:~/Downloads/linux$ ./run.sh
error: device not found
```

adb is installed.

I switched on the USB-Debugging as asked and it wants to use the PTP instead of the MTP (which I think I did, but nothing changed).

Installed Chrome and used Helium as a Chrome-App instead. No changes still.

I'm pretty much suck now. Fairphone doesn't offer any other support than relying on Google to solve that issue for them and I'm not aware of other backup-options.

What's the easiest way to do a backup?

Comment: [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/131553) will help but in addition you may need third party tools to back up contacts. SMS etc

Comment: @beeshyams - contacts, SMS are exactly my problem. I don't know how to do a backup on them

Comment: Helium only cares for apps and their data. It is based on ADB Backup, which is known not to cater for SMS either. The question @beeshyams linked tries to sum up how to achieve a full backup (as full as possible). Our [backup tag-wiki](/tags/backup/info) does give you an overview as well. With your device not rooted, you will probably need a combination of apps plus ADB to achieve your goal.

Comment: [for sms and contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160461/131553) see this

Comment: @Izzy - thanks for the link. Actually there is a lot of useful stuff to be found. Some tutorials inclusive. Just what I needed. Would just be great if some tutorials would be linuxier.

Comment: @Qohelet I know what you mean (I'm a Linuxian as well). To quote your name-sake indirectly: "there is a place for everything". Only few found ours it seems :) And btw: keep in mind our nice tag-wikis. Many of our tags have them :)

Comment: @Izzy - I will. I'd just wish Google would keep them in mind too ;)